# Common denominator with radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Can you make these 2 fractions into 1?

> $$2\sqrt{9-2x} - \dfrac{2x}{\sqrt{9-2x}}$$

I thought you could make them into $ \dfrac{-2x+18}{\sqrt{9-2x}}$

Comment: rather $18-4x-2x$ in the nominator

Comment: You're right, thank you.

Comment: Else it's maximally ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost correct.

\begin{align} 
2\sqrt{9-2x} - \frac{2x}{\sqrt{9-2x}} &= 2\sqrt{9-2x} \times \frac{\sqrt{9-2x}}{\sqrt{9-2x}} - \frac{2x}{\sqrt{9-2x}}\\ 
&= \frac{2(\sqrt{9-2x})^2}{\sqrt{9-2x}} - \frac{2x}{\sqrt{9-2x}}\\ 
&= \frac{2(9-2x)}{\sqrt{9-2x}} - \frac{2x}{\sqrt{9-2x}}\\ 
&= \frac{2(9-2x) - 2x}{\sqrt{9-2x}}\\ 
&= \frac{18 - 4x - 2x}{\sqrt{9-2x}}\\ 
&= \frac{18-6x}{\sqrt{9-2x}}
\end{align}

Comment: I assume that we should make the statement that $x$ is not equal 9/2.

Comment: That is implicit as soon as the initial expression is given. In fact, you need $x < \frac{9}{2}$.

Comment: OK, thanks, may be the OP should take notice.